# Is it possible to get the ProcessInstanceWorkItem.Id from a formula field?

Tags: apex, configuration

Can one use the ProcessInstanceWorkItem.Id field as a merge field in an email template? It doesn't look like this is possible, as it's only queryable via SOQL:

```
SELECT p.Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem p WHERE p.ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
```

I'm asking this question because I want to have a custom approval assignment email template specified that is able to leverage the link to the actual approval/reject step. This link is available in the default approval assignment email template, in this format:
'https://[yourInstance].salesforce.com/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=[Id]'. This is a helpful link as it saves a click step and is much clearer for those on mobile.

I did think to create my own email class which would handle the sending of the approval notification and the aforementioned link as it would be via Apex and  SOQL however, as per this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bq74AAC), if the approval notification template is not specified, the default one will *always* be sent out, which means that *two* emails would be sent to approvers - which would be confusing and noisy.

Comment: Formula? No. You could write a trigger to populate that data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of doing but then two emails will always be sent out. Thanks

Comment: No I don't mean a trigger to send an email, but rather to populate the Id.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just use a trigger to populate a custom field with the ProcessInstanceWorkItem and reference that custom field as a merge field in the approval notification email template. Got it.

Comment: Can you specify a Visualforce Email Template? If so, a Trigger might not even be needed - i'd create a Visualforce Component that handles querying for data and generating the link

Comment: Thanks for the great idea - i'll check it out. I wonder if I could use a VF email template and controller to attach attachments from an approval process? That would be such a clever way to bypass this limitation: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4D3AAI

Comment: This object is available via SOQL only.